# How to get best path from a set of path using Q-Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, reinforcement-learning

I have 10 data sets (lat and long) of the same path. I started from point A and stopped in point B and did this 10 times for a single route to get the data. While collecting the data, there were some fixed obstacles and some random obstacles. So, I avoided them. Doing this 10 times created a fixed curve in every dataset and some other ghost curves (as I avoided human and other obstacles). I want to remove these ghost curves and keep the actual curves in every dataset. Then I want to select one optimal path from these 10 paths. So can anyone suggest me what machine learning algorithm would be best fit for this work and if it can be solved using q-learning?

[image: Sample Dataset]

[image: here, 1 is actual obstacle and 2 is ghost obstacle]

1 is actual obstacles. 2 is ghost obstacle.

[image: I want like this. After stacking all the paths together, there will be only one obstacle]

I want like this.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What determines which path is optimal?  What is a "ghost curve"?  What is an "actual curve"?  Why do you think machine learning or q-learning is the right approach?  Can you show us a visualization of the 10 paths?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66470484/781723

Comment: edited. The link you have given was actually my question but nobody could answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to learn q-learning for this? It seems like a poor fit for your problem.

Comment: can you suggest something else? @awillia91 it would be a great help

Comment: Try [datascience.se].